# how to test toString() of Javascript in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to map response like below :

```
getData(){
     return data
     .map(subscription => ({
       id : subscription.id,
       productName: {
          toString: () => subscription.productName,
          name: subscription.productName
       }
    })
}
```

Explicit conversion like `toString: () => subscription.productName` is a requirement.

How do I test this `toString()` with `jest`? That statement remains uncovered in test.

Comment: What's `subscription` ? Please provide.

Comment: Update : I'm trying to map response inside function

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing:

`index.ts`:

```js
export const obj = {
  getData() {
    const data = [
      { id: 1, productName: 'github' },
      { id: 2, productName: 'reddit' },
    ];
    return data.map((subscription) => ({
      id: subscription.id,
      productName: {
        toString: () => subscription.productName,
        name: subscription.productName,
      },
    }));
  },
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { obj } from './';

describe('61953585', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const datas = obj.getData();
    expect(datas).toEqual(
      expect.arrayContaining([
        expect.objectContaining({
          id: expect.any(Number),
          productName: expect.objectContaining({
            name: expect.any(String),
            toString: expect.any(Function),
          }),
        }),
      ]),
    );
    const productName1 = datas[0].productName.toString();
    expect(productName1).toBe('github');
    const productName2 = datas[1].productName.toString();
    expect(productName2).toBe('reddit');
  });
});
```

The outcome for the unit test:

```js
 PASS  stackoverflow/61953585/index.test.ts (10.579s)
  61953585
    ✓ should pass (3ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.09s
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick repose @slideshowp2. The tests passes but the coverage is not yet achieved. No idea why I'm checking it

Comment: Adding more two tests like `expect(productName.toString).toBeInstanceOf(Function);` and `expect(productName.toString()).toBeTruthy();` worked for me with 100% coverage.